# warning MSB8012 - Linker's OutputFile property value ()

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild, msbuild-4.0, linker-warning

### warning MSB8012

I've read through many answers to people asking about this error, but none of them seem to have gotten such a problem as mine. I'm trying to use property sheets in my projects to save having to set up property settings every time, and in turn I'm getting this on build:

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(989,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\MyProj\Release\MyProj.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetExt(.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(991,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(MyProj) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
```

It'd be easy if all I had to do was change the Linker's OutputFile property value, but as you can see, it says `Linker's OutputFile property value ()` (OutputFile value is null?) each time, which is kinda different the `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)` I set it to be...

The only things I've configured in the property sheet are some debugging settings, some optimisation settings, adding a post-build event and disabling unicode. That's all I need, but this problem is now stuck in the project, even if I remove the property sheet. I've not converted the project from a previous version of Visual Studio at all, like so many who get this warning have, but just tried to add and configure a property sheet.

Here are some of the related settings:

General->Output Directory: `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\`

General->Target Name: `$(ProjectName)`

General->Target Extension: `.dll`

Linker->Output File: `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)`

At first I was just going to ignore this warning, but it actually started causing problems, so I'll be really grateful if someone can figure out this MS puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to start having an effect on all projects, so I reinstalled Visual Studio and the problem is gone... I'm scared to try and use property sheets again now, but it's better than nothing. I guess it was all MS' fault.

Comment: Property sheets are very usefull if you want to set up a common environment for multiple developers. They are a bit awkward to use, but once you get the hang of it, still usefull.